# PostgreSQL: transforming a column based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to transform `col_A` in my table based on the values like below:

```
col_A
----------------------------
Hello_axd_sdc_we_world
Hello_g_world
Hello_world
Goodbye_A
Goodbye_sdg_Sda
Goodbye
Goodbye_asd_asd_Sddg
```

I would like the transformed column `d_col_A` looks like:

```
col_A                            d_col_A
-----------------------------------------
Hello_axd_sdc_we_world           Hello_world 
Hello_g_world                    Hello_world 
Hello_world                      Hello_world 
Goodbye_A                        Goodbye
Goodbye_sdg_Sda                  Goodbye
Goodbye                          Goodbye
Goodbye_asd_asd_Sddg             Goodbye
```

And here is my rules:

```
If col_A starts with Hello and end with World
   Then d_col_A = Hello_Wolrd
If col_A starts with Goodbye
   Then d_col_A = Goodbye
```

Is this something possible? Thanks!

Comment: what's the rule? get first word and last ?

Comment: You'd need a 'rules' table or something to that sort to translate.  A list of conditions that if met translate to this value

Comment: rule table added. Thanks!

Comment: How many rules will your actual version have?  2 rules I'd hard code, more than that I'd suggest a reference table.

Comment: It will be a few dozens of rules. Would like to know the options for both hard code and reference table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table called 'lookup' or something to that extent as ID,first_param,second_param,translate_value

```
1,hello,world,hello_world
2,goodbye,null,goodbye
```

Now some join fun.  Postgres has a left() and right() and length() function that we can make use of here.  more complicated rule sets could also include a like function (third parameter = must contain this word?) if desired.

```
Select a.col_A , l.translate_value
from table_a a
left join lookup_table l
  on left(a.col_a,length(l.first_param)) = l.first_param
  and (right(a.col_a,length(l.second_param)) = l.second_param or l.second_param is null)
```

I did a left join so nulls get produced when the rules aren't met rather than dropping lines.  I lack a postgres test environment, but syntax should be right.

Case version

```
select case when left(col_a,5) = hello and right(col_a,5) = 'world' then 'hello world' 
case when left(col_a,7) = 'goodbye' then goodbye
else 'no clue what this means'
from table_a
```

Comment: What would be the option of  hard-code  in the query statement? As I might not have permission to create a table. Thanks!

Comment: Either create a temp table and populate prior (create table #tempparam as id int, etc... then insert into #tempparam values (1,'hello','world','hello_world' etc...).  Usually you can create temp table despite not being able to create a full table.  Or move the join conditions to a case statement in the select line (along the lines of select case when left(col_a,5) = hello and right(col_a,5) = world then 'hello world' else next condition etc end).

Comment: For what it's worth, the case statement is how I would have approached it if there was only 2 rules.  If there are 20 rules, you get 20 elses in that case statement and it gets bulky.  Since you said a few dozen rules, the table method is far cleaner.  though if you have some odd conditions (if it contains 'me', start with help, contains atleast 25 characters, and has 5 spaces then 'help me this is f-in messed!'), then the case statement gives more control

Comment: would u mind sharing the case statement approach just for this above example? Thanks!

Comment: edit up.   you may also want to know the substring() function as well.   If hello starts at the 6th character, substring(col_a from 6 for 5) will detect that.  https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php